# File provisioner in Packer for Windows Server

Tags: windows, azure, packer

Issue with File Provisioner for Windows Azure VM

We tried implementing the Packer template referring the Microsoft Docs-
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/build-image-with-packer#create-azure-resource-group

Also, we replaced the script with the provisioner block

Below is the JSON script used to deploy the File Provisioner

```
{
  builders: [{
    type: "azure-arm",

    "client_id": "",
    "client_secret": "",
    "tenant_id": "",
    "subscription_id": "",

    "managed_image_resource_group_name": "Packer-RG",
    "managed_image_name": "myPackerImage",

    "os_type": "Windows",
    "image_publisher": "MicrosoftWindowsServer",
    "image_offer": "WindowsServer",
    "image_sku": "2016-Datacenter",

    "communicator": "winrm",
    "winrm_use_ssl": true,
    "winrm_insecure": true,
    "winrm_timeout": "5m",
    "winrm_username": "packer",

    "azure_tags": {
        dept: "Engineering",
        "task": "Image deployment"
    },

    "location": "East US",
    "vm_size": "Standard_DS2_v2"
  }],
  "provisioners": [{
   "type": "file",
  "source": "C:/Test-1",
  "destination": "C:/Test-1"
  }]
}
```

After implementing the steps, the builds were finished but no artifacts were created.

Comment: Is it a good idea to post the `client_secret` in the question?

Comment: Use the latest version of Packer and this issue may go away. https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/21944